# TestStack.White trying to automate finding textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, automation

[image: Code with errors here]

I'm using the wrapper library TestStack.White for a simper way to dive into Windows Automation. I was trying to automate a way to enter your username on a game launcher. I don't know the textbox name so I tried using the SearchCriteria method to retrieve it.

From this I got the following errors

> - The best overloaded method match for 'TestStack.White.UIItems.Finders.SearchCriteria.AndControlType(System.Windows.Automation.ControlType)'
>   has some invalid arguments    C:\Users\Steve\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\SAML\Mod Loader\RunSA.xaml.cs   54  16
> - Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Type' to 'System.Windows.Automation.ControlType'    C:\Users\Steve\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2013\Projects\SAML\Mod Loader\RunSA.xaml.cs    54  65

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
SearchCriteria.ByControlType(ControlType.Edit)
```